How to save changes in .NET 8 EF Core DDD AggregateRoot design pattern
I am working on a HR management project and trying to save entity changes with EF Core and .NET 8.
Controller:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class LeaveController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public LeaveController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitLeaveRequest([FromBody] SubmitLeaveRequest submitLeaveRequest)
    {
        var command = new SubmitLeaveRequestCommand(GetCurrentUserId(), submitLeaveRequest.StartDate, submitLeaveRequest.EndDate, submitLeaveRequest.Reason);

        var data = await _mediator.Send(command);

        return CreateResponse(data);
    }
}

CQRS command handler:
public class SubmitLeaveRequestCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<SubmitLeaveRequestCommand, Unit>
{
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _repository;

    public SubmitLeaveRequestCommandHandler(IEmployeeRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<Unit> Handle(SubmitLeaveRequestCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var employee = await _repository.GetEmployeeByUserIdAsync(request.UserId);

        if (employee == null)
            throw new Exception("Not Found");

        employee.AddLeaveRequest(request.StartDate, request.EndDate, request.Reason);

        await _repository.SaveChanges(cancellationToken);

        return Unit.Value;
    }
}

The repository SaveChanges method (temporary method):
public async Task SaveChanges(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}

Now I have 2 main entities, Employee the aggregate root and LeaveRequest which is part of this aggregate.
public class Employee : AggregateRoot
{
    public string UserId { get; private set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public string Position { get; private set; }
    public Address Address { get; private set; }

    private readonly List<LeaveRequest> _leaveRequests = new List<LeaveRequest>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<LeaveRequest> LeaveRequests => _leaveRequests.AsReadOnly();

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(string userId, string firstName, string lastName, string position, Address address)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        UserId = userId;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Position = position;
        Address = address;

        AddDomainEvent(new EmployeeCreatedEvent(this));
    }

    public void AddLeaveRequest(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string reason)
    {
        var leaveRequest = new LeaveRequest(startDate, endDate, reason, Id);
        _leaveRequests.Add(leaveRequest);
        AddDomainEvent(new LeaveRequestAddedEvent(leaveRequest));
    }
}

public class LeaveRequest : Entity
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; private set; }
    public string Reason { get; private set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; private set; }
    public string? RejectionReason { get; private set; }
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; } 

    public LeaveRequest() {}

    public LeaveRequest(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string reason, Guid employeeId)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
        Reason = reason;
        IsApproved = false;
        EmployeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public void Approve()
    {
        IsApproved = true;
    }

    public void Reject(string rejectionReason)
    {
        IsApproved = false;
        RejectionReason = rejectionReason;
    }
}

When I try to save the changes that are made with the command handler, I get this error:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

The database looks fine, the necessary relationship is there, a simple one to many.
This is my context:
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LeaveRequest> LeaveRequests { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore<DomainEvent>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
        .OwnsOne(e => e.Address, a =>
        {
            a.Property(ad => ad.Street).HasColumnName("Street").IsRequired();
            a.Property(ad => ad.City).HasColumnName("City").IsRequired();
            a.Property(ad => ad.State).HasColumnName("State").IsRequired();
            a.Property(ad => ad.ZipCode).HasColumnName("ZipCode").IsRequired();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
           .HasMany(e => e.LeaveRequests);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasIndex(e => e.UserId)
            .IsUnique();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

I just don't understand why the SaveChanges does not work, I also track all the entities.
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>
(
    options =>
    {
        options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll);
        options.UseSqlServer
        (
            configuartion.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
        );
    }
);

I haven't tried many things, but I also could not find a good example to look at.

And your repository?

BTW QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll is the default one.

At least one of the potential problems I see is that you are generating Id values (primary keys). EF Core sees that entity has non-default id and considers that as existing entity and tries to update it, not insert (when you are saving entity added to the relationship), but since there is no such entry in the database you get the exception.
Make EF Core aware of the fact that Id is generated either by attribute:
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }

or via the fluent API:
modelBuilder.Entity<LeaveRequest>().Property(l => l.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

See also:

the Generated Values docs.
EF Core simple Logging (or just EF Core logging) - a very useful tool to check what is happening under the hood, like generated queries, etc.


I have the Id property in entity class, sorry for not providing that in the question. I have Ids and it is not Identity, I provide the value

@Imesashvili_Irakli thanks for the info) Yes, I figured that out, that Id is defined on the base class.
